# How to Report on Direct Messages in a Community

Tags: community, chatter, custom-reports, chat, direct-messaging

We are doing some proof-of-concept work to leverage the Direct Messaging feature in Salesforce Communities. We need to be able to run reports on the number of messages sent by Users, including details such as the sender, receiver and # of messages by date.

As per the Salesforce docs, I have ensured that I have the following permissions on my System Admin profile:

- Moderate Chatter
- Moderate Communities Chatter Messages
- Manage Chatter Messages and Direct Messages
- View All & Modify All

The Salesforce docs/resources indicate that, with these permissions, I should be able to create a custom report type and run a report on Messages. I have created a few messages between Users in a Community (see screenshot below), and I've tried a couple of ways to report on these messages with no luck. Here's what I've tried:

- Created a Report Type "Networks with Chatter Messages"... no results
- Ran a SOQL query on the ChatterMessage object... no results
- Installed the  Salesforce Communities Management application and ran some of the pre-created reports on Chatter Messages... no results

**Can someone please advise on how we can enable reporting on Direct Chatter messages?**

[image: Direct Messages Screenshot]

[image: Report Screenshot]